# Magento 1 session in database error with PHP 7.2

Tags: magento-1.9, session, php-7

Updated to Magento 1.9.3.10 with PHP 7.2. If I save the sessions in db:

`<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>`

I get this error:

`Recoverable Error: session_module_name(): Cannot set 'user' save handler by ini_set() or session_module_name()  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 83`

Comment: My vanilla Magento 1.9.3.10 works after installing the "PHP 7.2 support" patch only (which is strange as it is stated that with v1.9.3.9 it is not required). However, line 83 of Varien.php is empty for me. From what version did you upgrade?

Comment: I have magento 1.9.3.10. I have just downloaded the .zip from the site and row 83 is populated.

Comment: True that - a blank 1.9.3.10-setup got something at line 83. Install the PHP 7.2 support patch and you should be good to go (at least I can verify session storing in db is working that way) - https://community.magento.com/t5/News-Announcements/PHP-7-2-Support-Patches-for-Magento-1-are-now-available/td-p/106999.

Comment: For the record: `patch -p1 < PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2` --> `[...] patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php [...]`

Comment: Can you add the whole output from your patching statement? Are you using the patch for 1.9.3.1 - 1.9.3.9?

Comment: The patch works, I do not understand why the site says there is no need for 1.9.3.9.
Thz !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike stated in the download page at magento.com, Magento > 1.9.3.8 seem still to require the "PHP 7.2 support" patch `PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2`.

Full output should look like this:

```
λ patch -p1 < PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2
patching file app/Mage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Group.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Store.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Website.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Entity/Address/Attribute/Source/Country.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Address/Attribute/Source/Country.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Address/Attribute/Source/Region.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Store.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/install.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Observer.php
patching file lib/Varien/Autoload.php
patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/Sftp.php
patching file lib/mcrypt_compat/mcrypt.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/AES.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Base.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Blowfish.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/DES.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Hash.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/RC2.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/RC4.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Rijndael.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/TripleDES.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Crypt/Twofish.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/File/ANSI.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/File/ASN1.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/File/ASN1/Element.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/File/X509.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Net/SCP.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Net/SFTP/Stream.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Net/SSH1.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/PHP/Compat/Function/array_fill.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/PHP/Compat/Function/bcpowmod.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/PHP/Compat/Function/str_split.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/System/SSH/Agent.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/System/SSH/Agent/Identity.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/bootstrap.php
patching file lib/phpseclib/openssl.cnf
```