# Magento CE 1.9 Patch for PHP 7.2 - puzzle

Tags: php-7.2, magento-1.9.3.10

we're planning to upgrade PHP from 5.6.30 to PHP 7.2

I've downloaded this patch from the Magento site
PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2

I haven't seen that extension .2_v2 before and google couldn't help either.
(tars and .sh are more familiar for patches)
Can anyone tell me what I need to do in order to run it?
I can actually open it and read it with a text editor.
It looks like Unix shell script.

should I just run it as follows after we've upgraded PHP to 7.2?

```
  sh PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2
```

Another question we actually have Magento 1.9.3.10 installed and this patch are for 1.9.3.9, there isn't one for my version. Is this likely to be OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your webroot run

```
patch -p1 < PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2
```

This will apply the patch. However, this will apply the page on Magento core files only! Make sure that all your extensions are PHP 7.2-proof too.

And, referring to your second question - [Magento 1 session in database error with PHP 7.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249910/magento-1-session-in-database-error-with-php-7-2/249916#249916):

> Unlike stated in the download page at magento.com, Magento > 1.9.3.8 seem still to require the "PHP 7.2 support" patch PATCH-1.9.3.1-1.9.3.9_PHP7-2018-09-13-08-01-43.2_v2.